# How to install d3 version 3 using npm?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, npm, npm-install

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dE7y.png)Can anyone tell me how to install the third version of d3 using npm line to use it in reactJS. I used npm install d3@3.4.11 but an error occured that is shown in the picture.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just install with `npm i d3@3`, which will automatically match the latest version of 3.x.

Comment: really unfortunate that the guy didn't mark this as the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

Install the latest version of d3 using

> npm install d3

and now rename the version of d3 in package.json with your required version, but I think every version doesn't support this as I required to install version 3.4.11 but it threw errors so I renamed the d3 version with the latest version of d3 version 3 i.e, 3.5.17.
After entering your required version save that json file and type

> npm install

in your terminal...

Answer (score 1):

Just type in cmd or terminal `npm install d3@3.0.0` or whatever version you need.

Comment: Ya, I tried that command but it is showing the error that is mentioned in the picture above.

Comment: Yeah, but as you can see, error says `Cant find Python executable.` so I guess that installation of d3 is not the problem here.